# Crash on launch because app is taking too long - deadlock - keychain

Tags: ios, security, crash, deadlock, keychain

I have a little puzzle to solve... Our app is crashing on launch (the dreaded `badf00d` error, it's taking more than 5 seconds to launch) but we are not able to reproduce the issue. I was able to get crash logs from users. Unfortunately, I don't have the .ipad to symbolicate the crash entirely (stupid error).

However, I'm wondering if it's not possible to find out what's going on from the backtrace. It seems that there is a **deadlock** happening in some security code. It also seems that this happens when trying to **load the main view**. Is there any chance that this would be code signing related? Any insight would be helpful!

```
Date/Time:           2014-10-02 23:34:23.472 +1000
Launch Time:         2014-10-02 23:34:03.057 +1000
OS Version:          iOS 8.0.2 (12A405)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
com.myappsoftware.myapp failed to scene-create in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 4.230 (user 4.230, system 0.000), 10% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 1.039, 3% CPU

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36360540 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x36297eee _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 186
2   libxpc.dylib                    0x364077b8 xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 152
3   Security                        0x2b8dd310 securityd_message_with_reply_sync + 64
4   Security                        0x2b8dd48c securityd_send_sync_and_do + 44
5   Security                        0x2b8ea452 __SecItemCopyMatching_block_invoke + 166
6   Security                        0x2b8e96f6 SecOSStatusWith + 14
7   Security                        0x2b8ea36e SecItemCopyMatching + 174
8   My App                          0x003e6db2 0x3a000 + 3853746
9   My App                          0x0006bcd0 0x3a000 + 203984
10  My App                          0x0006bd28 0x3a000 + 204072
11  My App                          0x0006c8c4 0x3a000 + 207044
12  My App                          0x0004bf7e 0x3a000 + 73598
13  UIKit                           0x2bb1e12a -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 598
14  UIKit                           0x2bbc7e00 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 28
15  UIKit                           0x2bbc7d28 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 224
16  UIKit                           0x2bbc72be -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 70
17  UIKit                           0x2bbc6fee -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 574
18  UIKit                           0x2bbc6d58 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 40
19  UIKit                           0x2bbc6cec -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 180
20  UIKit                           0x2bb1b672 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 510
21  QuartzCore                      0x2b543cc8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 132
22  QuartzCore                      0x2b53f6b0 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 356
23  QuartzCore                      0x2b53f538 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 12
24  QuartzCore                      0x2b53ef1c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 220
25  QuartzCore                      0x2b53ed20 CA::Transaction::commit() + 320
26  UIKit                           0x2bd7f390 -[UIApplication _reportMainSceneUpdateFinished:] + 40
27  UIKit                           0x2bd80138 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 2508
28  UIKit                           0x2bd8a544 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 32
29  UIKit                           0x2bd7e554 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 128
30  FrontBoardServices              0x2edc10e6 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 10
31  CoreFoundation                  0x286465b2 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 10
32  CoreFoundation                  0x28645874 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 212
33  CoreFoundation                  0x286443ae __CFRunLoopRun + 1710
34  CoreFoundation                  0x2859261c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
35  CoreFoundation                  0x2859242e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
36  UIKit                           0x2bb8256a -[UIApplication _run] + 554
37  UIKit                           0x2bb7d354 UIApplicationMain + 1436
38  My App                          0x0004ac3a 0x3a000 + 68666
39  libdyld.dylib                   0x362adaac start + 0
```

I was actually able to symbolicate the crash. It's actually strange and definitely looks like a deadlock:

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a64d540 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a584eee _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 186
2   libxpc.dylib                    0x3a6f47b8 xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 152
3   Security                        0x2fbca310 securityd_message_with_reply_sync + 64
4   Security                        0x2fbca48c securityd_send_sync_and_do + 44
5   Security                        0x2fbd7452 __SecItemCopyMatching_block_invoke + 166
6   Security                        0x2fbd66f6 SecOSStatusWith + 14
7   Security                        0x2fbd736e SecItemCopyMatching + 174
8   My App                          0x004aadb2 +[SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:andServiceName:error:] + 390
```

I also have other stack traces where another thread is also stuck simultaneously at the same point:

```
Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.Flurry.Analytics.Session
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x37c07540 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x37b3eeee _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 186
2   libxpc.dylib                    0x37cae7b8 xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 152
3   Security                        0x2d184310 securityd_message_with_reply_sync + 64
4   Security                        0x2d18448c securityd_send_sync_and_do + 44
5   Security                        0x2d1910fa __SecItemAdd_block_invoke + 158
6   Security                        0x2d1906f6 SecOSStatusWith + 14
7   Security                        0x2d190ac6 SecItemAdd + 338
8   My App                          0x000c57a4 -[FlurryKeychainWrapper setData:forKey:] + 144
9   My App                          0x000c569a -[FlurryKeychainWrapper setObject:forKey:] + 66
10  My App                          0x000b75a8 -[FlurrySession initialTimestamp] + 880
11  My App                          0x000b66a4 -[FlurrySession dataForSessions:] + 872
12  My App                          0x000b503c -[FlurrySession sendSessionsToServerIncludingCurrentSession:] + 624
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x37b348c8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x37b3c64c _dispatch_queue_drain + 948
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x37b37098 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 80
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x37b3db9e _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 318
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x37b3ecd2 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 90
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37c95e2e _pthread_wqthread + 666
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x37c95b80 start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: The question is similar to
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827809/app-rejection-crash-report-says-failed-to-scene-create-in-time-badf00d-what

Comment: @Kamchatka are you able to solve this issue ?

Comment: @nivritgupta We haven't heard of the issue again. IIRC We asked users to update their iOS version.

Comment: @Kamchatka Thanks  for the update i already solved this issue

Comment: @Kamchatka Can you share how you fixed that issue? We're experiencing same deadlocks now on iOS 9.3.3

Comment: We've asked the users to update their iOS version at the time and never heard of this issue again.

Comment: We've just seen this too; an app was rejected by App Review with a stack trace nearly identical to the above. Guess this is still a problem, and on App Review's devices, too. My workaround is to put the code that interacts with the Security framework in a secondary thread.