# Is there a way to stop an app from closing if it stalls on splash screen?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I've been testing an app for iOS in Xamarin Studio, however whenever I reach a breakpoint or an exception is thrown and I stay there for a few seconds without pushing the continue execution button, the debugging session will close as the app will close on my device. This is due to the process mentioned [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26955459/3624389) as it is occurring during the splash screen, and if the app pauses too long there, it will close the app because it failed to scene-create. I was wondering if it is possible to disable this when debugging with breakpoints, because I would like to look at the data flow through variables and such.

Comment: It sounds like this is a Xamarin issue. I don't use Xamarin, but there is no such closure when you run from Xcode. You _cannot_ stop an app that is not running from Xcode from being killed if it pauses for too long on the main thread; that is the job of the _watchdog process_, and it is just doing that job. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

Comment: @matt thanks for that info, i shall see if i can make an xcode project in xamarin studio and then run that.

Comment: Watchdog is not a factor when debugging.

Comment: @quellish the exception I'm getting is 0x8badf00d which "indicates that an application has been terminated by iOS because a watchdog timeout occurred."

Comment: Shouldn't get that while the debugger is connected - please file a radar

Comment: @quellish done, will update question with anything i hear back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As matt guessed, it is a Xamarin issue. The response to my inquiry to Xamarin was this,

> Xamarin does not currently use a native debugger, thus watchdog is not
>   disabled. They are looking into alternatives, but for now a potential
>   workaround is to not do anything until you've returned from the
>   FinishedLaunching method (i.e. start your launch code in a timer event
>   for instance), and debug that instead.

Update: the status on this bug is "fixed for the next major release." as of 12/29/15