# iPhone app fails to launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9, xcode7

I am running my app in `iPhone5s` running on `ios9.1`

When I run app via xcode7.02 connected via USB then it launches.

But when I tap the icon after disconnecting from my mac then I see Splash Screen for Some time and then my App closes giving a feel like that is crashes.

I connected my device to my system and saw the logs.I am not getting what is the main problem. Here is the device logs:

I am posting the useful info which I think is:

```
Application Specific Information:
com.company.app failed to scene-create after 19.63s (launch took 0.37s of total time limit 20.00s)

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 11.150 (user 11.150, system 0.000), 28% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.924, 2% CPU
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827809/app-rejection-crash-report-says-failed-to-scene-create-in-time-badf00d-what

Answer (score 1):

i hope you are using distribution or adhoc certificates,Please use development certificates

Answer (score 0):

you can add an **All Exceptions** point to your project.

If you can see a crash when you run app via xcode7.02 connected via USB, you will get more information about the crash.I got a similar problem.